# How do I get rid of Cygwin's /cygdrive prefix in all paths?

Tags: path, cygwin, bashrc

I'm switching to Cygwin from the bash shell that ships with Git for Windows, and encountering a strange problem.  Someone thought it would be a good idea to add `/cygdrive/` to all paths, while I think it's a horribly ugly idea.  I've been able to determine that I can partially fix this by adding

```
mount --change-cygdrive-prefix /
export HOME=/c/Users/BZISAD0
```

in my .bashrc, but if I take a look at the PATH variable, everything still has /cygdrive/ in it.  I suppose I could write a script to fix the PATH but that's even more kludgey than what I'm already doing.  There's got to be a better way, and I'm pretty confident there is since Git's bash shell uses (AFAIK) an older version of Cygwin, and it's somehow configured to *not* prepend `/cygdrive` everywhere.  So, how can I [turn the "Suck" knob to zero?](http://www.talkbass.com/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=236041&d=1321250798)

[image: Gary Larson comic]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Grepping around in /etc turned up [a link](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive) that Googling did not.  It turns out you can control this in the file `/etc/fstab`.  Just add a line that says

```
none / cygdrive binary 0 0
```

and the problem should be fixed.  No more kludgey fixes in .bashrc, and no messed-up $PATH.

Comment: I used this method, and now when I try to do `ls /`, the windows drives don't appear. Not even when using `ls -l /`. Is this expected? Can it be fixed? This is what I have in fstab: `none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,user,acl 0 0`

Comment: I didn't know there was a way to get the windows drives at `/`.  Did you have that before?  (Or at `/cygdrive/`?)  I've always just lived with the fact that I have to know which Windows drives are available, and I hardly ever use them anyway.

Comment: I don't really know... I never tried it before.

Comment: Yes, `ls /cygdrive` should list the Windows drives. The output for me, for example, is `c/ e/ f/`. Note how drives are treated like folders.

Comment: This only half works. The two mounts (real `/` and `cygdrive`) are sort of overlaid. That is: you can get at the drives using `/c`, _etc._ - but they are never listed as part of `/`. I think the real `/` is hiding the contents of `cygdrive` when listing. I'm wondering if this is technically undefined behaviour and might conceivably break something. Anyway, since I prefer to be able to see anything I'm working with, I'm choosing `/mnt`.

Comment: @underscore_d: fair enough.  thanks for the info!

Comment: works pretty good! love it.

Comment: @Tibi I discovered that if you cd to / and then do mkdir c (or whatever the name of your drive is), it will make that drive mount point visible to ls, instead of overwriting it with an empty directory.  Who would have thought?

Answer (score 12):

Method one

```
mount -c /
mount -m > /etc/fstab
```

Method two

```
echo - / cygdrive acl > /etc/fstab
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/e1c6ddf/.cygwin#L49)

Comment: both before and after doing this (method 1), `/` referred to the cygwin64 root directory, and `cd /c` did not work. To make `cd /c` work I had to do `mount c: /c` .

Comment: `/c` should never have worked, my solution never suggested that

Comment: I interpret "how to get rid of /cygdrive in paths" to mean "how to allow /c to work instead of /cygdrive/c " (and similarly for other letters)  . My PATH does now indeed show /c/bla instead of /cygdrive/c/bla

Comment: As of 2.9.0(0.318/5/3) 2017-09-12 10:18 x86_64 Cygwin, doing method one will allow user to `cd /c` or `cd c:`. Using `cd /` still goes to the cygwin64 dir.

Answer (score 4):

What about cygpath (Convert Unix and Windows format paths, or output system path information)...

```
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32

$ cygpath -w $(pwd)
C:\Windows\System32
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [mount](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#mount) should work.

```
mount -c /
```

If you still have entries in `PATH` that refer to `/cygdrive`, then you probably just need to reboot.

Also, check if there are any `PATH` settings in `/etc/profile` that refer to `/cygdrive`.

Comment: You mean restart Cygwin, or actually reboot the whole machine?

Comment: I think you need to terminate *all* Cygwin-based processes.  The easiest way to do this is to reboot the machine.

Comment: I normally give preference to other people's answers when I find answers to my own questions, but since yours requires a reboot (or simulation thereof) and since mine is the one found in cygwin's documentation, I'm going with mine.

Comment: If yours worked without a reboot, then by all means!

Comment: But if I reboot the machine, this change is gone. Back to what is stored in fstab.

Answer (score 1):

Another point that wasn't mentioned is that different flavors using the Cygwin DLL use different configurations (like the above). One example would be Git for Windows, which is based on MSYS which in turn uses Cygwin.

The unified way to access the "Unix" path across these flavors is to use `/proc/cygdrive`; this way it doesn't matter if `cygpath -u D:\` returns `/d` or `/cygdrive/d`.

The common prefix can also be got from `cygpath` using the `-U` switch.

PS: Since this doesn't answer the question, but sidestep the underlying issue (except for the cosmetic one), I am making this CW.